# Plotly Hides Markers on Line Chart

Tags: javascript, plotly

I'm trying to create a line chart with markers for about 30 data points using Plotly.  For some reason Plotly decides to hide the markers when the data points goes above a certain threshold such as 15.  There is no reason to hide them as there is more than adequate space available.  See below:

```
var trace1 = {
  x: [1, 2, 3, 4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20],
  y: [1, 2, 3, 4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20],
  type: 'line',
  marker: {
    size: 10,
  },
};

var data = [trace1];

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data);
```

https://codepen.io/ceds/pen/OJMOjjB

Any idea how to disable this?

Comment: I can not see markers on line, did you tried this property `mode: 'lines+markers',`?

Comment: That's the point... if there is less than 15 data points then markers are displayed.  Otherwise they disappear.  But using the mode you suggested solved the problem.  Please post the answer and I'll mark it as the correct answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not getting the exact problem why its not showing when more than 15 data points, But i have a solution using `mode: 'lines+markers'` property for marker and lines, as below,

```js
var trace1 = {
  x: [1, 2, 3, 4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20],
  y: [1, 2, 3, 4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20],
  type: 'line',
  mode: 'lines+markers',
  marker: {
    size: 10,
  },
};

var data = [trace1];
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data);
```

```html
<head>
    <!-- Load plotly.js into the DOM -->
    <script src='https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id='myDiv'><!-- Plotly chart will be drawn inside this DIV --></div>
</body>
```

Hope this help.